# How to find infimum and supremum of an inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Given $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (2x^2+x-21)(x^2+2x)<0\}$, I want to find $\inf(A)$ and $\sup(A)$ and to if it admits minimum and/or maximum.

First of all, I've solved the inequality, which gives me that for $]-2:-\frac{7}{2}[$ and $]0:3[$ is negative, whereas the other parts of the domain are positive. I think the maximum of the function, in this case, are indeed $-2;-\frac{7}{2};0;3$, but I don't know how to find $\inf(A)$. Moreover, how do I know if it admits minimum and/or maximum?

Comment: It's simply $inf(A)=-2$ and $sup(A)=3$.

Comment: I think your solution is not right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is $$
A = \left[-3.5, -2 \right] \cup [0,3].
$$
Here, we used to $-\dfrac{7}{2} = -3.5$.
Let is a definition: "If $A$ is bounded above, then a number $x$ is said to be a supremum (or a least upper bound) of $A$ if it satisfies the two conditions:

(1) $x$ is an upper bound of $A$ and

(2) if $y$ is any upper bound of $A$, then $x \leq y$".

So, if $-2$ is not a supremum of $A$, because $-2$ is not an upper bound of $A$.
So, the supremum is a number 3.

The same way to an infimum, i.e., $\inf A = -\dfrac{7}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you got that
$$A = \left\langle -2,-\frac72\right\rangle \cup \langle 0,3\rangle$$
so $\inf A = -2$ and $\sup A = 3$. Neither is attained.